# Why not work createFisherFaceRecognizer() in opencv java?

Tags: java, android, opencv

Hellow

I want to create face detected? and predicted them from base? for this i  read i need createFisherFaceRecognizer(), dut when i try to add this in my project write that is not this in my libarary i use 2.4.9,can you help me.

Bottom i fetch code it not work.

Sorry for my bad English

FaceRecognizer rec = new FaceRecognizer();

this method is not work too

```
FaceRecognizer rec=createLBPHFaceRecognizer();
or
FaceRecognizer rec=createEigenFaceRecognizer();
or
FaceRecognizer rec=createFisherFaceRecognizer();
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can't use the FaceRecognizer classes from java at all in `OpenCV 2.4.9`. Cause of there is no proper way to wrap a `cv::Ptr<FaceRecognizer>`, so those classes (or rather the `create...()` functions) are skipped during the wrapper code generation.